# Powershell - Trouble with Out-File - Insert a count variable into file name

Tags: powershell

I would like the file to save with the count variable between the file prefix and the file extension. Out-File (file prefix + count variable + file extension).  sort of thing. I'm ridiculously new to Powershell so please be merciful :P

```
$max = get-content h:test1\test.txt | Measure-Object 
$h = get-content h:test1\test.txt
For($i=0; $i -lt $max.count ; $i++){
select-string h:test2\*.txt -pattern $($h[$i]) | Format-List | Out-File (Join-Path h:\text  $i)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
Out-File h:\text\$i.extension
```

PowerShell's parsing gives rise to a few very weird problem in edge cases, but overall it is designed to work as you would expect it to work in most, if not all, common cases.

In your case I would probably solve the problem a little differently:

```
Get-Content h:\test1\test.txt |
  ForEach-Object { $i = 0 } {
    Select-String H:\test2\*.txt -pattern $_ |
      Format-List |
      Out-File h:\text\$i.extension
    $i ++
  }
```

The first block for the `ForEach-Object` in this case is run once at the start of the loop and initialises the counter variable. I tend to avoid explicit looping constructs (such as `for (x; y; z)` or `foreach (x in y)`) in favour of pipeline solutions.

Comment: Get-Content $file[x] |
...
Out-File h:\text\$file[x][i].extension   

sort of thing.

Comment: Kurtis, if you have another question, then ask another question. And please include more detail, as I currently don't really understand what you're up to.

Answer (score 1):

```
select-string h:test2\*.txt -pattern $($h[$i]) | Format-List | Out-File "h:\text$i.txt"
```

Like any good scripting language there are a multitude of ways to accomplish a goal, but that is one that should work for you.